# byte[] to .eps image

Tags: c#, eps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting .EPS to Image in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095071/converting-eps-to-image-in-c-sharp)

How to convert byte array to .eps image in C#?

I have a code which works with graphic images(`.jpg`, `.png`...) but it throws an argument exception when I'm converting to `.eps` format.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

using (ms)
{
      //saving image on current project directory
      Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);

      img.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "file.eps");
}
```

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095071/converting-eps-to-image-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you need to use the Image after conversion or only to save it to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you've posted it seems that you only save an image to a file with *.eps extension. If it's so, you don't have to create a `MemoryStream` object at all, just use this method:

```
try
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "file.eps", byteArray);
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    //your exception handling code here
}
```

It should work for all types of files, but without verifying if the file content's is a valid image. However, if you are sure what the file's contents are, it should be good method to use in this case. This method, however, can throw a number of exceptions, so be sure to handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to save it you can save it using the class [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx):

```
byte[] buffer  = ms.GetBuffer();
File.WriteAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "file.eps", buffer);
```

Comment: I've got an unauthorized access exception. It may be because the byte array I'm working with is in database. I am just guessing

Comment: You can try to use directly `byteArray`, if you don't need the memorystream.